# My lawn is full of wild strawberries. What else can thrive in my soil?

Tags: soil, lawn, strawberries

My lawn seems to have more wild strawberries than grass (especially in the shady areas), which means it needs some work.  But if it can support strawberries, there must be some great fruits/vegetables/flowers that will grow great in the soil.

What does this indicate chemically about my soil?  What else will thrive?  (Zone 5B)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This page](http://yourorganicgardeningblog.com/weeds-ph-and-other-soil-indicators/) suggests that you have acid soil (there are other pages that make the same suggestion, but this was the first hit):

> Weeds for Acid Soil: Dandelions, Weeds, common mullein, wild strawberries. Instead of them, you can grow azaleas, blueberries, hydrangeas, rhododendrons, endive, potatoes, shallots.

For what it's worth, I also have tons of wild strawberries in a new garden patch that was tested last fall to have a pH of 5.0. (And blackberries, oh the blackberries!)

So plant potatoes and shallots for the main course, and some blueberries for dessert. :)

Comment: Hi bstpierre! For me that link redirects to a German company, https://gartopia.net. which, according to Google Translate, focuses on sales of garden equipment. I use Firefox and live in the United States, so it could be my problem! Obviously the answer's perfect, and you quoted something, so it might not be worth looking for another source. Mostly I just wanted to let you know! I hope you're having a productive growing season!